# Hit URL On Server To Automate An Action Executed By Server

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I want to hit URL on my server via Swift function to automate an action executed on server. I don't need a response. I just need to hit the correct URL on server. I need the swift code (function) to execute this. I had this working in old swift but it does not work anymore in swift 3. I need to hit two URL's with one action via UISwitch in app. Your help would be much appreciated and please provide the full code of function to perform task as I am new. Your help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hit your url along with Thread,

```
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

            // do things which can run in background
            // calculations-delay-waiting for a response etc.

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {

                // implement UI related part which has to run in main thread.


                }

            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved my problem...

```
 func functionName () {
    //  Trigger Automation URL
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.handofgodapp.com/automate?key= SUQ3VExRg==&activate=1")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let session = URLSession.shared

    session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, err in
        print("Entered the completionHandler")
        }.resume()
}
```